# Facebook page tab too high

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook page tab. I don't want to have scrollbars, so I resize the canvas using FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();:

```
<body>
    <p>My app</p>
<script>
FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading(function(response) {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
</script>
</body>
```

My body css:

```
body {
width: 810px;
height: 100%;
margin:0;
}
```

When I view the app inside the page tab frame, the scrollbars are gone, but at the bottom of my app, there is whitespace, because the body of the app is made too high. When I test outside the frame, the body height is good, it just fits the content as it normally does. So my app body is made too high inside the page tab frame, for some reason. This is how it looks:
[image: My app inside facebook page tab]

I tried many different ways of resizing the page tab canvas, and I tried many css changes.
I have made Facebook page tab apps before, also with resizing the canvas, and this was never a problem.

Does anyone have a solution how to make the page tab frame fit the app content?

Thanks,
Simon